# What is the difference between nexttick and onupdated?

Tags: vue.js

I am following some tutrials to lear how `nexttick` works, but i could not grasp the difference between it and `onUpdated`. As shown below the qoutations sections they almost occur or get called for the same reason.
to understand it further, i created the below posted code. and as shown `nexttick` is called after `onUpdated`

can you please tell me the difference between `nexttick`  and `onUpdated`

**onUpdated**:

```
[link][1]
The onUpdated() lifecycle hook is called just after a DOM update has occurred, meaning immediately after the onbeforeUpdate hook is called.
```

**nexttick**:

```
[link][1]
Defer the callback to be executed after the next DOM update cycle
Use it immediately after you’ve changed some data to wait for the DOM update
```

**code**:

```
<div>
    <button @click="handleClick">Insert/Remove</button>
    <div v-if="show" ref="content">I am an element</div>
</div>

<script setup>

import { reactive,nextTick, ref } from 'vue'
import { onBeforeMount,onMounted,onUpdated,onBeforeUpdate,onActivated,onDeactivated,onBeforeUnmount,onUnmounted } from 'vue'

const show = ref(true)
const content = ref()

const handleClick = () => {
  show.value = !show.value
  console.log(show.value, content.value)
  nextTick(() => {
    console.log(show.value, content.value)
  })
}
</script>
```

**output**

first run:

```
onBeforeMount
onMounted
false <div>​I am an element​</div>​
onBeforeUpdate
onUpdated
false null
```

second run:

```
true null
onBeforeUpdate
onUpdated
true <div>​I am an element​</div>​
```

Comment: nextTick callback will also get called even if no changes happen, onUpdated might not get called at all if there is no changes.

Comment: I think that `nextTick` could be deferred if multiple changes/updates are queued, e.g. if `onUpdated` causes update in a child component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vue.js, both nextTick and onUpdated are methods used in different scenarios to handle asynchronous updates and perform operations after the DOM has been updated. Here's a breakdown of each:

**nextTick**:
The nextTick method is used to schedule a callback function to be executed after the next DOM update cycle. It is essentially a way to queue a function to be run after the DOM has been patched. This is useful when you need to wait for Vue's reactivity system to update the DOM before performing certain operations.

Example usage:

javascript

```
// Inside a Vue component
this.$nextTick(() => {
  // DOM has been updated, perform operations here
});
```

The callback function passed to nextTick will be invoked after the DOM has been updated with the latest data changes.

**onUpdated**:
The onUpdated lifecycle hook is a method that is called after the component has been re-rendered and the updated virtual DOM has been patched onto the actual DOM. It is a lifecycle hook specifically provided by Vue for performing actions after a component has been updated.

Example usage:

javascript

```
// Inside a Vue component
export default {
  // ...
  updated() {
    // DOM has been updated, perform operations here
  },
  // ...
}
```

In this case, the updated method will be called every time the component is re-rendered and the DOM has been patched.

To summarize:

**nextTick** is a method that allows you to schedule a callback function to be executed after the next DOM update cycle. It's useful for performing operations that depend on the updated DOM state.
**onUpdated** is a lifecycle hook that is called after the component has been re-rendered and the updated virtual DOM has been patched onto the actual DOM. It's useful for executing actions specifically after a component update.

Both nextTick and onUpdated serve different purposes and should be used based on your specific requirements.

Comment: thank you.referring to your elaboration about onupdated, according to my understanding, onupdated must be declared in <script setup> and not in export-default!am i wrong?

Comment: It doesn't **have** to be declared there and could be in both if i'm not mistaken. I'm more familiar with Vue2 then Vue3. I have no experience with '<script setup>' whatsoever, so I could be wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

`nextTick`:

- It is typically used when you want to perform some action after the
  DOM has been updated in response to a data change.
- `nextTick` allows you to wait for the DOM update to complete before
  executing code that relies on the updated DOM.
- It is useful when you need to access the updated DOM elements or
  measure their dimensions after a data change.

`onUpdated`:

- It is triggered after the component has been re-rendered due to a
  reactive data change or a parent component update.
- The `onUpdated` hook allows you to perform operations or access the
  updated DOM immediately after it has been re-rendered.
- It is useful when you need to interact with the updated DOM elements
  or perform additional actions based on the updated component state.

So basically their main difference is that `nextTick` is a utility function used to schedule a callback to be executed after the next DOM update cycle, while `onUpdated` is a lifecycle hook that is automatically triggered after a component has been re-rendered due to a reactive data change or a parent component update.